# How to migrate PostGIS databases between Postgres versions?

Tags: postgis-2.0

Mac OS

I am trying to upgrade my Postgres version 9.2 to 9.6 and failing.  My strategy was to follow the standard advice for Postgres databases and use pg_dumpall.  This does not appear to work if you are using PostGIS extensions because the dump contains 1000s of references to the actual PostGIS library on disk.  [See this.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291443/postgres-is-loading-wrong-postgis-library)

So how does one move around PostGIS databases without links to actual libraries embedded in them?

Comment: Have you considered OGR2OGR? I'm assuming both PostGIS installs are working properly you should be able to use OGR2OGR -f  PostgreSQL but you must manually create the database(s) the layers are going into see https://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html for limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_dumpall` should work. Make sure that you have already installed the new PostGIS extension, and that you are **not** using the `--clean` option.

Doing so, it will try to recreate the old PostGIS items but will fail since they already exist, and move on to the next item.

Comment: It does not work in my case because the tables were created with a version of Postgres older than 9.2.   It was at 9.2 that the extension management changed and decoupled the extension from the from the library file on disk.   I have accepted this answer as correct as it answers the question as asked.   At the time I was unaware of the migration issues with tables created by earlier versions.